# How to downgrade iPhone 3GS to iOS 4.x?

Tags: ios

I've spent a whole day trying the different solutions one can find by Google-ing this.

- Using Xcode to downgrade
- Downloading the firmware image and providing it to Xcode
- Using iTunes
- Using an old computer that the phone was sync'ed to back in 2009 (funny enough, I have two of them)
- Using the iRestore and libusb

So far the only thing I've seen is the phone getting stuck in DFU mode or a message saying that it can't be downgraded (I forget the exact language).

It would seem that Apple would provide for a way for developers to do this sort of thing without this much pain an agony.  I have eight iOS devices, four of which are permanently devoted to development, two iPods and two iPhone 3GS.  The two iPods stayed with iOS 4.x.  Both 3GS's where accidentally upgraded to iOS 5.  I wanted one to stay with 4.x for the time being.

Do I have any options beyond what I've tried?

Apple:  A little developer love would go a long way here.  It's enough to have to deal with all the stuff that breaks from release to release of the OS and Xcode.  At least make this easy. 
Pretty please?
With sugar on top?
(Had to try)

**The question was marked closed.  I don't understand why.**

According to the FAQ:

"Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- **software tools commonly used by programmers**
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

This question relates to **software tools commonly used by programmers working on iOS devices**.

And, in fact, it is a huge problem due to the fact that it impedes proper testing on the platform.  Perhaps someone in this community has better ideas that can be brought to the surface.  That was the intent.

"Questions on Stack Overflow **are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way**"

I think **this question definitely relates to software development**.

Re-open it please.  This is a big problem.